# Querying EWS with phone number

Tags: soap, exchangewebservices

I want to do a lookup from contacts using a phone number. I've tried the `FindItem` soap but couldn't get it to work for some reason. I was trying something like below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?> 
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/messages" 
xmlns:t="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types" 
xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<soap:Body> 
    <m:FindItem Traversal="Shallow"> 
        <m:ItemShape> 
            <t:BaseShape>AllProperties</t:BaseShape> 
        </m:ItemShape> 
        <m:IndexedPageItemView MaxEntriesReturned="1000" Offset="0" BasePoint="Beginning" /> 
        <m:Restriction> 
            <t:Contains ContainmentMode="FullString" ContainmentComparison="IgnoreCase"> 
                <t:FieldURI FieldURI="contacts:PhoneNumbers" /> 
                <t:Constant Value="SOMEPHONENUMBER" /> 
            </t:Contains> 
        </m:Restriction> 
        <m:ParentFolderIds> 
            <t:DistinguishedFolderId Id="contacts" /> 
        </m:ParentFolderIds> 
    </m:FindItem> 
</soap:Body>
```

But I'm getting a `"Property cannot be used with this type of restriction"` error. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use that strongly type property in a Restriction, You might want to try using the Extended property for each phone number you want to Search eg for Businessphone number use https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-r/cc839937.aspx eg

```
        <m:Restriction>
      <t:IsEqualTo>
        <t:ExtendedFieldURI PropertyTag="14856" PropertyType="String" />
        <t:FieldURIOrConstant>
          <t:Constant Value="9999-9999-999" />
        </t:FieldURIOrConstant>
      </t:IsEqualTo>
    </m:Restriction>
```